# Column moved while merge excel files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I tried to merged all excel files and all of them only contain 1 column. However, the merged data was moved the next column. Does anyone know how to fix that?
Here is the Python code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
file_path = "c:\merge-excel"
files = (file_path+"/*.xlsx")
all_files = glob.glob(files)
merged_data = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(a) for a in all_files])
merged_data.to_excel (file_path+"/Merged_files.xlsx", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

file 1.xlsx:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

file 2.xlsx:

```
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

file 3.xlsx:

```
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

Merged_files.xlsx:

```
1 | 8 | 16
2
3
4
5
6
7
   9
   10
   11
   12
   13
   14
   15
        17
        18
        19
        20
        21
        22
        23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the default value of the `header` parameter to [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) is `0`, which means it is taking the first row in each excel file and using it as a column header. So you have 3 columns `1`, `8`, and `16` which were the first row's value in each file. Use

```
pd.read_excel(a, header=None)
```

to work around this.